# Understanding bitwise operations on a byte array

Tags: java

I am trying to develop a program to read certain type of file and extract all the package information of this file in bit level.

The packet is divided as:

- SYC: 8 bits
- TEI: 1 bits
- PSI: 1 bit
- TP: 1 bit
- PID: 13 bits
- TSC: 2 bits
- AFC: 2 bits
- CC: 4 bits

My question is: how do I get the bits separately? For example the PID, 5 bits are in position 1 of the array and 8 bits in position 2; how can I get this information from 2 separate bytes and sum them afterwards?

I have this sample code to get the PID and it reproduces the correct result:

```
int PID1 = (buf [1] << 8) | (buf [2] & 0xff);
```

I don't understand this equation, especially `buf [1] << 8`. Could someone explain to me this equation and what should I do to get the rest of the package information?

Comment: Have a look at [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) or maybe [Java Bit Manipulation Guide](http://sys.cs.rice.edu/course/comp314/10/p2/javabits.html), or simply Google [`java bitwise operators`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+bitwise+operators&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: I already saw these @Andreas. My question is: I need to get 5 bits from a byte and sum with another 8 bits. In this case, why use buf[1] << 8, what is the mean of this 8 to my question? why not a 3 because I just need 5 bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '<<' operator moves the bits position to the right in binary which is essentially the same as multiplying by two.

This code :

```
byte buf[] = new byte[2];
buf[1] = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    int bshifted = buf[1]<<i;
    System.out.println("buf[1]<<"+i+" = " + Integer.toBinaryString(bshifted) +"(binary) = "+ bshifted + "(decimal)");
}
```

Produces this output:

```
buf[1]<<0 = 11(binary) = 3(decimal)
buf[1]<<1 = 110(binary) = 6(decimal)
buf[1]<<2 = 1100(binary) = 12(decimal)
buf[1]<<3 = 11000(binary) = 24(decimal)
buf[1]<<4 = 110000(binary) = 48(decimal)
buf[1]<<5 = 1100000(binary) = 96(decimal)
buf[1]<<6 = 11000000(binary) = 192(decimal)
buf[1]<<7 = 110000000(binary) = 384(decimal)
buf[1]<<8 = 1100000000(binary) = 768(decimal)
```

The whole expression `(buf [1] << 8) | (buf [2] & 0xff)` has the effect of moving buf[1] out of the low order 8 bits of the int and putting only the low order 8 bits of buf[2] into that part of the integer.